# To pick relevant color code depending on a given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

So if the value of `zoneTempDiff1` is less than say suppose 1.5 then temp: 1 color should be considered , if the value of `zoneTempDiff1` is greater than 1.5 then temp:2 color should be considered.
Likewise for all the different values and if it is -1 or -2 or 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then the respective temp value color
And if value of `zoneTempDiff1` is greater than +6 or -6 then the respective temp:-6 or temp:+6 color should be taken

```js
floor.entities.forEach(elementId => {

  let objTemp: any = {};

  objTemp.currentTemp = 68;
  (values might be different)
  objTemp.desiredTempHeating = 70.5;
  (values might be different)

  let zoneTempDiff1 = objTemp.currentTemp - objTemp.desiredTempHeating;
  let tempColor1 = this.temperatureColors.filter(color => zoneTempDiff1 < (color.temp + 1) && zoneTempDiff1 > (color.temp - 1));
  objTemp.tempColorToInsert = tempColor1.color;

  floor.droppeditem.push(objTemp);
});
```

```js
temperatureColors: any = [{
    color: '#50B3D3',
    temp: -6
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -4
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -3
  },
  {
    color: '#7EE2DD',
    temp: -2
  },
  {
    color: '#7EE2DD',
    temp: -1
  },
  {
    color: '#89DE6F',
    temp: 0
  },
  {
    color: '#89DE6F',
    temp: 1
  },
  {
    color: '#D2E143',
    temp: 2
  },
  {
    color: '#D2E143',
    temp: 3
  },
  {
    color: '#FDCB31',
    temp: 4
  },
  {
    color: '#FDCB31',
    temp: 5
  },
  {
    color: '#F59A4A',
    temp: 6
  }
];
```

Comment: Are you trying to get just one value back? If so, that might be problematic b/c you could have multiple values coming back. What does `this.temperatureColors` look like? Since you're `filter`ing on that array, multiple temperatures could be within your filter condition. Also, `filter` returns a new array so you're not accessing `tempColor1` correctly. You'd need to at least do `tempColor1[0]` to get the first entry properly.

Comment: @hellatan this.temperatureColors strcuture I have posted in que, depending on zoneTempDiff1 value I have to pick color from this.temperatureColors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your question exactly?

We call the function like this:

```
getColor(68, 78, colors);
```

We pass in the current temperature, the desired temperature and the array of color objects.

```
const getColor = (current, desired, colors) => {
```

Then we figure out the difference between temperatures and [round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) it to the nearest whole number.

```
const diff = Math.round(current - desired);
```

We get the index of the last element in the colors array

```
const last = colors.length - 1;
```

Now we check to see if the difference is **less or equal** to the temp property given in the *first* color object of our array. If it is, we can return the color and we're all done.

```
if (diff <= colors[0].temp) return colors[0].color;
```

Basically the same thing here but we check to see if we are **greater or equal** to the temp in the *last* color object in the array.

```
if (diff >= colors[last].temp) return colors[last].color;
```

Since it's not one of those two, we need to run through the array and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object that **equals** the diff.

```
return colors.find(color => diff === color.temp).color;
```

Does this help?

```js
const colors = [{
    color: '#50B3D3',
    temp: -6
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -5
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -4
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -3
  },
  {
    color: '#7EE2DD',
    temp: -2
  },
  {
    color: '#7EE2DD',
    temp: -1
  },
  {
    color: '#89DE6F',
    temp: 0
  },
  {
    color: '#89DE6F',
    temp: 1
  },
  {
    color: '#D2E143',
    temp: 2
  },
  {
    color: '#D2E143',
    temp: 3
  },
  {
    color: '#FDCB31',
    temp: 4
  },
  {
    color: '#FDCB31',
    temp: 5
  },
  {
    color: '#F59A4A',
    temp: 6
  }
];

const getColor = (current, desired, colors) => {
  const diff = Math.round(current - desired);
  const last = colors.length - 1;
  if (diff <= colors[0].temp) return colors[0].color;
  if (diff >= colors[last].temp) return colors[last].color;
  return colors.find(color => diff === color.temp).color;
}

console.log(getColor(68, 78, colors));
console.log(getColor(78, 68, colors));
console.log(getColor(78, 72, colors));
console.log(getColor(78, 73, colors));
console.log(getColor(73, 78, colors));
console.log(getColor(73, 73.8, colors));
console.log(getColor(73, 73.4, colors));
```

**Ok, new function.**

This time we just get the diff and then use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to pick the color object we want from the array. It's less code (hell, it's a one-liner) but it's a little bit harder to decipher. It's also a little more resilient, you don't need every temperature difference in the input array.

```js
temperatureColors = [{
    color: '#50B3D3',
    temp: -6
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -4
  },
  {
    color: '#25CBE4',
    temp: -3
  },
  {
    color: '#7EE2DD',
    temp: -2
  },
  {
    color: '#7EE2DD',
    temp: -1
  },
  {
    color: '#89DE6F',
    temp: 0
  },
  {
    color: '#89DE6F',
    temp: 1
  },
  {
    color: '#D2E143',
    temp: 2
  },
  {
    color: '#D2E143',
    temp: 3
  },
  {
    color: '#FDCB31',
    temp: 4
  },
  {
    color: '#FDCB31',
    temp: 5
  },
  {
    color: '#F59A4A',
    temp: 6
  }
];

const getColor2 = (current, desired, colors) => colors.reduce((acc, cur) => (current - desired) >= cur.temp ? cur : acc).color;

console.log(getColor2(68, 78, temperatureColors));
console.log(getColor2(78, 68, temperatureColors));
console.log(getColor2(78, 73, temperatureColors));
console.log(getColor2(73, 78, temperatureColors));
console.log(getColor2(73, 73.8, temperatureColors));
console.log(getColor2(73, 73.4, temperatureColors));
```

**Reduce**

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works on an array. It feeds each array element to a callback and eventually returns a **single** value.

For example, let's say we have an array `[1, 2, 3]`. A simple example is to reduce the array to a sum of all of its elements. The reduce callback is what does all of the magic.

The callback gets 4 arguments: an accumulator, the current element, the index of the current element and the array itself.

Let's take a side track and explain the accumulator. This is the magical piece of the puzzle. The value of the accumulator is available on every "loop" of the array. So if the callback returns something, it gets placed in the accumulator. When reduce is done looping through every element, it returns the accumulator. This is the *single value* that finally gets returned.

So essentially, the callback given to the reduce function is just there to manipulate the accumulator.

What does the accumulator start at? That depends.

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(callback);
```

The accumulator will start with the *first* array element (`1`) and start looping at the **second** element.

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(callback, 0);
```

Here, we have initialized the accumulator to *zero* and reduce will start looping with the **first** element.

So if we want to add up our array, we can say:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce( (accumulator, current) => accumulator + current )
```

This will add the current value to the accumulator and return it and keep doing that for each element of the array.

In this case:

```
const getColor2 = (current, desired, colors) => colors.reduce((acc, cur) => (current - desired) >= cur.temp ? cur : acc).color;
```

we loop through your array of objects. If the temperature difference is greater or equal to the temperature in the current object, then we set that object to the accumulator. When it is all done, return the accumulator and one object pops out.

You could use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) but that would take a more complicated comparison that has to decide if your diff is between two values. I just kept looping through and updating the final value.

It goes, hey, is -1 greater than -6? Yeah? Cool, -6 is our boy. Next loop, hey is, -1 greater than -4? Yeah, ok, -4 is the one we want. Next loop, is -1 greater than ... Eventually you hit, 0 and the accumulator stops getting updated. It loops through the rest of the elements of the array and decides that it isn't greater than any of those values so the accumulator never gets updated. The last thing we assigned to the accumulator gets spit out and that's the object we wanted.

Comment: thanks , but I guess it fails to pick color if values are 66.6 - 72 , I mean this is the value for me that fails , could you please suggest

Comment: So here 66.6 - 72 comes to round -5 and then in last find check I get -5 === -6 which doesn't give me any color, please suggest

Comment: I think -5 values are failing to pick color, any suggestion on this, thanks

Comment: Ah, I'd add it to the input array.

Comment: Till date I am not able to understand reduce , I have referred to mdn as well , could you please explain , what is the difference between the 1st and 2nd solution of yours , thanks

Comment: thanks for such a beautiful explanantion , could you please suggest on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58500914/to-open-popup-modal-based-on-the-box-position