# To open popup modal based on the box position

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want the popup modal opening where the box is. For the top 2 boxes placed the modal opens correctly, I was trying for the last 2 boxes placed at the bottom as well.

```
{
 top: 0 + 'px'+ this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop + 'px',
 right: ((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) - x.left) - 20 + 'px',
 height: 'auto',
 width: 58 + '%',
 display: 'flex'
};
```

I tried adding offsetop but then the modal is placed at the bottom.

Reproducible stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbxxgr?file=src/app/app.component.scss

**Without adding any top value(works for top 2 boxes)**(Same expectation is for the bottom 2 boxes)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufwotn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I want a similar kind of behavior as happening for 1st 2 boxes, whenever I hover over the bottom 2 boxes the modal is opening from the top near the 1st 2 boxes, whereas the expectation is till wherever I have scrolled then from their top of the screen the modal should open

Comment: `this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop` does not take into account the position of the scroll

Comment: Yes I tried taking scroll into account but it was not working

Comment: Please, show this

Comment: @Enthu so when user click on the bottom boxes you need to scroll up to the top am i correct ?

Comment: The modal should opening should be similar to what is happening for the top 2 boxes

Comment: @YashRami I have given one more link for top 2 boxes popup

Comment: @Enthu So the problem is while i hover over the bottom 2 boxes model position is wrong am i correct?

Comment: @YashRami Yes now whenever I hover for the bottom 2 boxes the modal is opening from top near to the 1st 2 boxes, whereas the expectation is till wherever I have scrolled then from there top of the screen the modal should open, hope I am clear

Comment: it's a very old, but [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313), another more early [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974557/how-to-create-a-container-for-all-selected-items-from-dropdown/66012553#66012553). The docs about [cdk-overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) and an application in this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905665/how-to-build-a-colour-pallete-in-dropdown-in-angular/73908751#73908751)

Answer (score 1):

try to use your variable with getBoundingClientRect, little example, change:

```
this.modelstyle {
    top: 0 + px;
  ...here other your code...
}
```

to

```
this.modelStyle {
   top: x.top + window.scrollY + 'px',
...here other your code...
}
```

Comment: Popup opens up only not where the box is and the red arrow is also getting displaced for 2nd box

Comment: so you need to open 3 and 4 popups not near the red boxes but at the bottom of the document right?

Comment: I want similar kind of behaviour as happening for 1st 2 boxes , whenever I hover for the bottom 2 boxes the modal is opening from top near to the 1st 2 boxes, whereas the expectation is till wherever I have scrolled then from there top of the screen the modal should open

Comment: check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufwotn?file=src/app/app.component.ts