# Angular CDK Overlay: how to calculate projected content height/width

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-cdk

I'm using Angular CDK Overlay. One of the properties in config is FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy. Im trying to attach overlay on top of my click trigger. All is working fine when there is enough space on top to fit overlay. What Id like to do is check if there is not enough space at the top then attach overlay to the bottom of the trigger. To do that I need some way after calling Overlay.open(...) to get access to projected content so i can calculate it's dimensions. Is there way to do that?

So far I only see hackish way to access internal _projectedViews[] array but its undocumented feature. Trying to find cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrei, when you define the cdk-overly you choose the "positionStrategy". The order of the positions is defined in the array withPositions. You can see this link (I don't know if is a bit outdated or not): [netanet basal cdk overlay](https://netbasal.com/context-menus-made-easy-with-angular-cdk-963797e679fc) (really the Angular material cdk-overlay is very poor), that I try to simply in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313)

Normally you import the overlay and the overlayPositionBuilder

```
constructor(public overlay: Overlay)
```

You create the overLayRef using create

```
const overlayRef = overlay.create();
```

The function create is an object of type [OverlayConfig](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#OverlayConfig) with properties: Height, width, maxWidth,.. and (among others) positionStrategy, that is an object of type [PositionStrategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#PositionStrategy)

So first you create an object of type PositionStrategy. For this you can use the the method `position()` of overlay

This object has the method flexibleConnectedTo

You can choose "connected" to ElementRef | HTMLElement| Point & { width?: number; height?: number;};

this return a [FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy) that you can give value to positions (an array of [ConnectionPositionPair](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#ConnectionPositionPair)), or directy or using the method withPositions

so, e.g.

```
const positionStrategy = this.overlayPositionBuilder
      .flexibleConnectedTo({ x, y })
      .withPositions([{
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'top',
        overlayX: 'center',
        overlayY: 'bottom',
      },
      {
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'bottom',
        overlayX: 'center',
        overlayY: 'top',
      }]);
```

make that try first attach to top, but if there're no enough space use the second defined position

**Update**

Well, de final position can be get enclosed in a setTimeout() after execute the attach, e.g.

```
   //After attach
   this.overlayRef.attach(new TemplatePortal(menu, viewContainerRef, {
            $implicit: data, close:this.close
        }));
    //enclosed in a setTimeout() we has this.overlayRef.overlayElement
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.overlayRef.overlayElement.getBoundingClientRect())
    })
```

Comment: btw @Eliseo is there way to tell which position strategy was chosen by CDK? I need to adjust some classes in overlay based on that

Comment: Cdk choose first the first position, if there're no space, get the second position... What position get it? After attach the element you can get the overlayRef.overlayElement, see the updated response: (I don't know if this is wat are you looking for)

Comment: I tried that but thought it would be little hackish. After more searching I found that CDK exposes panelClass as porperty in position. CDK then injects that class if this particular position strategy was chosen. That solved problem for me.