# Create a Small Dialog Attached to an Element Using CDK/Overlay

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I need to create small dialogs, attached to elements. So I find the element using its ID, then I need to show a small dialog near it, with some text and buttons.
I need to do this from a service, because I need it to be dynamic and used in different parts.
So I use this to find the element by ID:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#' + step.stepAnchor);
```

I was able to generate a dialog:

```
    // We create the overlay
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create();
    //Then we create a portal to render a component
    const componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(PopoverComponent);
    // We add a custom CSS class to our overlay
    this.overlayRef.addPanelClass("popover");
    //We render the portal in the overlay
    this.overlayRef.attach(componentPortal);
```

But I don't know how to attach it to the element I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than targeting element IDs, I recommend using a directive for a case like this since the generated popover component is supposed to be positioned relative to a particular element on the page. I made a StackBlitz to demo my suggestion, but it basically executes the setup logic you wrote in each directive instance instead but configures it more specifically. It also includes a service that will allow you to toggle any registered popover from anywhere:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lui6d5?file=src/app/popover-host.directive.ts