# How to put mat-sort-header in menu

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

can anyone tell me how to extract the `mat-sort-header` functionality from the headers into a menu.
I want to open a menu when I click on one of the header. Within this menu I want to use the `matSort` functionality.

In fact, I want to trigger the `matSortChange`  event

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about "contextual menu" and "mannage mat-sort". It's a broad question and really I don't know how answer, so a brief data

If you see the [source of matSort](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/sort/sort.ts). You can "override" the method sort.

You can use some like

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.sort.sort=(sortable: MatSortable)=>{
      //this only to update the variables active and direction
    
      if (this.sort.active != sortable.id) {
        this.sort.active = sortable.id;
        this.sort.direction = sortable.start ? sortable.start : this.sort.start;
      } else {
        this.sort.direction = this.sort.getNextSortDirection(sortable);
      }
      
      //this make the table sorted
      this.sort.sortChange.emit({active: this.sort.active, direction: this.sort.direction});
    }

    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

So you can choose "not emit the change" or emit in a contextual menu.

For contextual menu you can use cdk-overlay. It's not well documented, but if you want an example, sometime ago I wrote this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313).

Another option is that each td of your header was a mat-menu

NOTE: I don't know how many is your knowledge in Angular, so it's possible this answer don't help you so much. Give us more data

**Update** well, we has all necesary with this data, so go on!

First we "override" the sort function to do nothing and create a new function to make the sort

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.sort.sort=(sortable: MatSortable)=>null
    this.dataSource.sort=this.sort
  }
  sortTable(active:string,direction:string)
  {
    this.sort.active=active
    this.sort.direction=direction as SortDirection
    this.sort.sortChange.emit({active: active, direction: direction as SortDirection});
  }
```

Then use mat-menu in the th. So our th will be like

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="positionTrigger.openMenu()">
      <span mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="position" #positionTrigger="matMenuTrigger">No.</span>
      <mat-menu #position="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="sortTable('position','asc')">
          <mat-icon
            *ngIf="sort.active=='position' && sort.direction=='asc'"
            >checked</mat-icon
          ><span>Ascend</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="sortTable('position','desc')">
          <mat-icon
            *ngIf="sort.active=='position' && sort.direction=='desc'"
            >checked</mat-icon
          ><span>Descend</span>
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

Finally we need some .css to "remove" the arrow that material add.
In styles.css

```
.custom-table .mat-sort-header-arrow
{
  visibility:collapse;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

And to beauty our menu in component.css

```
button.mat-menu-item
{
  
  height: 1.75rem!important;
  font-size:12px;
  text-overflow: unset;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

button.mat-menu-item >span
{
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left:24px;
}
button.mat-menu-item .mat-icon+span
{
  padding-left:0;
}

.mat-menu-item .mat-icon
{
  font-size:12px;
  height:1.75rem!important;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top:1rem;

}
```

the result in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqam1n?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)