# Get max value from Angular Material Table / JSON array

Tags: json, angular, pipe

I have created a function to map over a json data to display it as a table using Angular Material.
I would like to

1. Display the highest bidamt and the corresponding from my table in my  and
2. Currently my id is arranged in order of timing (i.e. an earlier entry is displayed as 1, a later entry is displayed as 2 etc.). How can I rearrange it to display it in order from highest to lowest bid?

bid.component.html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="highest-amount">
            <span class="highest-amt-text">{{bid.bidamt | max}}</span>
            <span class="highest-amt-name">{{bid.name | max}}</span>
        </div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" 
        matSort matSortDisableClear matSortActive="bidamt" matSortDirection="desc">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No.</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let bid"> {{bid.id}} </td>
          </ng-container>
           <ng-container matColumnDef="bidamt">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Bids</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let bid"> {{bid.bidamt | number}} UCD</td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="bidname">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let bid"> {{bid.bidname}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator
          style="color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          [pageSize]="2"
          [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 5, 10]"
          aria-label="Select page">
        </mat-paginator>
      </div>
```

bid.json

```
{
  "bids": [
    {
      "bidamt": 500,
      "bidname": "Alice",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "bidamt": 300,
      "bidname": "Ben",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "bidamt": 2000,
      "bidname": "Clare",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

bid.component.ts

```
export class BidComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit { 
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'bidamt', 'name'];
  dataSource!:MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator! : MatPaginator; 
  @ViewChild(MatSort) matSort! : MatSort;

  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription;

  constructor(private BidService: BidService){ }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.BidService.getBids().subscribe((response:any) =>{
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
      })
  }

}
```

Comment: Please show the parts in your .ts file where you connect the matsort to your datasource.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I have added, thanks

Comment: I think `@ViewChild` is only bound in a later lifecycle step, so you should be assigning `matSort` and `paginator` in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approach:

1. Sort the array before create the data source

   ```
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response
                           .sort((a,b)=>a.bidamt-b.bidamt));
   ```
2. Create a function like

   ```
     sortTable(active:string,direction:string)
     {
       this.sort.active=active
       this.sort.direction=direction as SortDirection
       this.sort.sortChange.emit(
              {active: active, direction: direction as SortDirection});
     }
   ```

   And call after asign the sort

   ```
   ...
   this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
   this.sortTable('bidamt','asc')
   ```

To know the max and store in a variable. first declare

```
max:number=0
```

then, simple use reduce of the array in subscribe

```
 this.BidService.getBids().subscribe((response:any) =>{
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
    this.max=response.reduce((a,b)=>b.bidamt>a?b.bidamt:a,-1000)
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort; //<--add this line
  })
```

Then you can use to add a class in the row

```
   <tr mat-row [class.highest-amt-name]="row.bidamt==max" 
        *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

or using style-background

```
   <tr mat-row [style.background-color]="row.bidamt==max?'red':null" 
        *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

If you want to use in a span you simply use

```
  {{max}}
```

**Update** we can add a new property "order" (or reemplace the "id" by order) using simply sort and map, e.g.

```
response=response.sort((a,b)=>a.bidamt-b.bidamt)
        .map((x:any,i:number)=>({...x,order:i}))
//or
response=response.sort((a,b)=>a.bidamt-b.bidamt)
        .map((x:any,i:number)=>({...x,id:i}))
```

See how we use the spread operator (the `...`x) to create an object with all the properties of the object and a new property "order" or a change of the property "id")

**update 2**
if we want to get the "element" with a "bidamt" greater. Using reduce we can do

```
this.max=response.reduce((a,b)=>b.bidamt>a.bidamt?b:a,response[0])
```

Well, if we already have the array sorted is simple

```
    reduce[0] //the first element or 
    reduce[reduce.length-1]  //the last element
```

in this case max is an object, so to compare the row we need use max.bidmat

```
  <tr mat-row [style.background-color]="row.bidamt==max.bidmat?'red':null" 
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Comment: instead of have direction as a string then type it SortDirection have the type of direction as SortDirection. this way IDE and typescript compile helps you catch errors

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen, you're correct, better use SortDirection.asc (I must recognize I copy +paste the function from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619489/how-to-put-mat-sort-header-in-menu/70620410#70620410) -where I need call to the function from .html and I was lazy to declare a public variable equal SortDirection-

Comment: @Eliseo sorry I think I didnt explain my question well. The two methods you suggested are based on sorting the existing ids with respect to the bidamt but keeping their original id intact. I would like to generate new numbers based on the bidamt e.g. 1. 2000, 2. 500, 3. 200 rather than right now which is 3. 2000 1. 500 2. 300

Comment: @xxavierxx, update the answer, simply sort and map the array

Comment: Hi @Eliseo your solution worked great for my second question on how to rearrange the ids. However since my highest-amt-name class lies outside my table which is where my [dataSource]="dataSource" lies, how would I refer to max?

Comment: `max` is a new variable that you calculate in your subscribe function (1). You use in mat row as `<tr mat-row [class.highest-amt-name]="row.bidamt==max" *matRowDef="let row;...>` or in html like `{{max}}` (1) you declare and use this.max=...

Comment: Hi @Eliseo think your previous comment got shorten as it was too long, would you mind completing your previous sentence please

Comment: @xxavierxx, I update the answer again adding the information for "max", I hope this can help

Comment: @Eliseo This works perfectly, thanks so much!! Sorry to trouble but would you also have to know how to retrieve the corresponding name with the highest bidamt?

Comment: @xxavierxx, just do it -see the updated answer. See that reduce makes a loop over an array. At first a is an initial value and b is the first element of the array. The function `(a,b)=>function` return a value -that must be the same type of "a"-. In the first reduce (who return the max) the a initial is a number, so return a number, in the second reduce,(who return an object)a is an object of type {id:..,bidamt:..,bidname:...}. In the second time a is the value calculate in the function and b is the second element of the array, in third a is the value calculate and b is the third element...