# How to get Component reference(this) in D3 Context Menu OnOpen and OnClose

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm new to `Angular` and trying to add `d3-context-menu` in my `Angular` project. I successfully added `Context Menu` when user do right-click.

```
this.svg = d3.select(this.elementRef.nativeElement)
  .append('div')
  //.on('click', (d, this) => this.onClickTask(d3.event,taskData, this))
  .on('contextmenu', contextMenu(this.menuItems, {
    onOpen: () => {
      // const status = this.MycomponentVariable;   // issue here to get "this" of my component
      console.log('Menu has been OPENED.');
    },
    onClose: () => {
      // const status = this.MycomponentVariable;    // issue here to get "this" of my component
      console.log('Menu has been closed.');
    }
  }));
```

But the problem I facing that I want a `variable` (this.MycomponentVariable) value of my `angular component` via `this`(component context) when `contxt-menu` is opened or closed. But it shows that `this` is `undefined`. So, I'm unable to get value of `this.MycomponentVariable`.

I read documentation of `d3-context-menu` over [this-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-context-menu) but couldn't get any solution.
Can anyone help me out that how can I get my `angular component context` inside `onOpen` and `onClose` methods?

Comment: why not use a more angular way? see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313) (and the links proposed)

Comment: Actually client demands to add `d3-context-menu`. So I have to use this approach only.

Answer (score 1):

Really use d3 (or jQuery) is not a great idea, but I imagine you can always create and dispach a CustomEvent.

```
this.svg = d3.select(this.elementRef.nativeElement)
  .append('div')
  .on('contextmenu', contextMenu(this.menuItems, {
    onOpen: () => {
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('menu',{detail:'Open'}}));
    },
    onClose: () => {
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('menu',{detail:'Close'}}));
    }
  }));
```

And use rxjs fromEvent operator

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuObs=fromEvent(document,'menu').subscribe((res:any)=>{
        console.log(res.detail)
    })

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.menuObs.unsubscribe()
  }
```