# How to make a notification div be always in front of everything, even dialogs?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, alert

I am trying to make a notification system in my project. We use angular-material and many dialogs from there.
So my question is how to make the notifications div to be always in front even dialogs?
Even putting a bigger z-index isn't working, it is appearing in front of everything else but the dialog.

this is my html :

```
<div
    class="notifications-container"
>
    <div
        *ngFor="let notification of notifications"
        class="{{ cssClass(notification) }}"
    >
        <a class="close" (click)="removeNotification(notification)"
            ><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></a
        >
        <span [innerHTML]="notification.message"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my css:

```
.notifications-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999!important;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: I believe mat-dialogs force themselves in front of the "furthest forward" element on screen. I don't think you can get "on top" of them without changing their behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular material use cdk-overlay to make the dialog box.

If you use F12 (to see the .html) you see that it's create a div "cdk-overlay-container" outside the angular app. So the only is create another "cdk-overlay" an put in this the "nofitication"

In this ["a bit old SO"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313) is created a cdk-container that show a template.

The steps to create a cdk-container that store a template are
1.-Create the template, some like

```
<ng-template #template let-data let-close="close">
  {{data|json}}
<button (click)="close()">close</button>
</ng-template>
```

2.-Use a ViewChild to get the reference of the template and inject in constructor Overlay and ViewContainerRef

```
@ViewChild('template',{static:true}) 

constructor(private overlay: Overlay,
            private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) {}
```

3.-create a function to "close" the cdk-container

```
close=(data: any)=> {
    if (this.overlayRef) {
        this.overlayRef.dispose();
        this.overlayRef = null;
    }
}
```

4.- When we want to create the cdk-container it's only make

```
this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({panelClass:'notif'})
this.overlayRef.attach(new TemplatePortal(this.template, this.viewContainerRef, 
     {
          $implicit: {data:'I\'m the button '}, close:this.close
      }));
```

5.-don't forget add in styles.css some like

```
.notif{
  z-index:9999
}
```

See that you need put the .css in a style that affect to all the application, don't work if you use the app.component.css

see a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-zxp14h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot.
In my case I wanted to have always a div open in overlay to loop the notifications inside, and I just had to put the function openNotif() in a ngAfterViewInit(). Now I can manage what comes inside this overlay template.