# How can I put a custom menu inside a column for each row of the table?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid

Inside a table component I am placing a button and on its click I want to open a menu (like in given screenshot link) which will have options to perform various actions. How to do that?
[Table with Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpPaQ.png)

Comment: I don't know what you have tried. But If you're already using angular material maybe the menu could help you <https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples>

Comment: For contextual menu, Take a look this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313) -and the links attached-

Comment: @FlorenciaCames This is what I needed. I'm new to angular, didn't realise there is already an option to add menu in angular material. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular material library you can have expandable rows in which you can populate different data accordingly.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows