# <ng-template> inside <ng-container> with cycle *ngFor for open panel with different data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this Htlm file, the first part **ng-container** work well and display correctly the data, but when click on the button and open the details panel, the panel use the **ng-template** so are not rendered correctly with the data of cycle for...I see always only the first data of the array.
I think that we have to generaty dinamically the template, but I don't know...
how can solve this problem?

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let member of members; trackBy: trackByFn;">
    <div class="flex flex-col py-4 sm:flex-row sm:items-center">

        <div class="flex items-center">

            <!-- Info details panel button -->
            <ng-container *ngIf="members?.length">
                <button class="w-5 h-5 ml-1 min-h-5"
                    [disabled]="member.session.length === 0"
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="openInfoDetailsPanel()"
                    #infoDetailsPanelOrigin>
                    <mat-icon
                        [ngClass]="{
                            'text-gray-400 icon-size-8': member.session.length === 0,
                            'text-green-600 icon-size-8': member.session.length > 0
                        }"
                        [svgIcon]="'cast_connected'">
                    </mat-icon>
                </button>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Info details panel -->
            <ng-template #infoDetailsPanel>
                <div class="flex flex-col py-4 px-6 w-full max-w-160 space-y-1.5 border text-md rounded shadow-md overflow-auto bg-card">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <span>{{member | json}}</span>
                        <span>{{member.session | json}}</span>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of member.session">
                            <tr>
                                <td  class="px-2 ">{{item.ip}}</td>
                                <td  class="px-2 ">{{convertDateTimeToLocaleDate(item.registrationDate)}}</td>
                                <td  class="px-2 ">{{convertDateTimeToLocaleTime(item.registrationDate)}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

In the file TS I have this function:

```
@ViewChild('infoDetailsPanelOrigin') private _infoDetailsPanelOrigin: MatButton;
@ViewChild('infoDetailsPanel') private _infoDetailsPanel: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and the function are:

```
openInfoDetailsPanel(): void
    {
        // Create the overlay
        this._overlayRef = this._overlay.create({
            backdropClass   : '',
            hasBackdrop     : true,
            scrollStrategy  : this._overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
            positionStrategy: this._overlay.position()
                                .flexibleConnectedTo(this._infoDetailsPanelOrigin._elementRef.nativeElement)
                                .withFlexibleDimensions(true)
                                .withViewportMargin(16)
                                .withLockedPosition(true)
                                .withPositions([
                                    {
                                        originX : 'start',
                                        originY : 'bottom',
                                        overlayX: 'start',
                                        overlayY: 'top'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        originX : 'start',
                                        originY : 'top',
                                        overlayX: 'start',
                                        overlayY: 'bottom'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        originX : 'end',
                                        originY : 'bottom',
                                        overlayX: 'end',
                                        overlayY: 'top'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        originX : 'end',
                                        originY : 'top',
                                        overlayX: 'end',
                                        overlayY: 'bottom'
                                    }
                                ])
        });

        // Create a portal from the template
        const templatePortal = new TemplatePortal(this._infoDetailsPanel, this._viewContainerRef);

        // Attach the portal to the overlay
        this._overlayRef.attach(templatePortal);

        // Subscribe to the backdrop click
        this._overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => {

            // If overlay exists and attached...
            if ( this._overlayRef && this._overlayRef.hasAttached() )
            {
                // Detach it
                this._overlayRef.detach();
            }

            // If template portal exists and attached...
            if ( templatePortal && templatePortal.isAttached )
            {
                // Detach it
                templatePortal.detach();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When create the templatePortal, the variables in your .ts are accesibles

But futhermore you can pass data, like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313)

```
const data={prop1:'',prop2:''}
const templatePortal = new TemplatePortal(
        this._infoDetailsPanel, 
        this._viewContainerRef,
        {
           $implicit: data
        });
```

If in your template you use

```
 <ng-template #infoDetailsPanel let-data>
   You can use
      {{data.prop1}} {{data.prop2}}
 </ng-template>
```