# Open Material menu at mouse position in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

When triggering a Material menu (mat-menu) it opens relative to the clicked object (above, below, before, after). My object is a very large container so I need the menu to open at the mouse position when clicking for a better user experience.

How can I do this?

I am using Angular 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a custom directive that extends the material menu.

```js
import { ConnectedPosition, FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuPanel, _MatMenuTriggerBase } from '@angular/material/menu';

// @Directive declaration styled same as matMenuTriggerFor
// with different selector and exportAs.
@Directive({
    selector: `[matContextMenuTriggerFor]`,
    host: {
        class: 'mat-menu-trigger',
    },
    exportAs: 'matContextMenuTriggerDirective',
})
export class MatContextMenuTriggerDirective extends _MatMenuTriggerBase {
    private lastMouseEvent: MouseEvent | null = null;

    // Duplicate the code for the matMenuTriggerFor binding
    // using a new property and the public menu accessors.
    @Input('matContextMenuTriggerFor')
    get menu_again() {
        return this.menu!;
    }
    set menu_again(menu: MatMenuPanel) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    // Override _handleMousedown, and call super._handleMousedown
    _handleMousedown(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.lastMouseEvent = event;
        super._handleMousedown(new MouseEvent(event.type));
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // Can't just override a private method due to how the lib is compiled
        this['_setPosition'] = (menu: any, positionStrategy: FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy) => {
            let positions: ConnectedPosition[] = [];
            super['_setPosition'](menu, {
                withPositions: (p: any) => {
                    positions = p;
                },
            });
            positionStrategy.withPositions(positions);
            if (this.lastMouseEvent) {
                positionStrategy.setOrigin({ x: this.lastMouseEvent.clientX, y: this.lastMouseEvent.clientY });
            }
            positionStrategy.withViewportMargin(10);
        };
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        super.ngOnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Use it likes this:

```
<div [matContextMenuTriggerFor]="nameOfMenu">Click to open menu</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling the following function when clicking the triggering object.

```
    positionItemMenu(event: MouseEvent) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const menuCollection = document.getElementsByClassName(
            'cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box',
        ) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
        const menu = menuCollection[0];
        menu.style.position = 'absolute';
        menu.style.left = event.x + 5 + 'px';
        menu.style.top = event.y + 5 + 'px';
    }, 0);
}
```

One problem however is that this breaks the build in functionality that prevents the menu from overflowing ouside of the screen. Another problem is that it goes back to original position if scrolling the page when the menu is still open. So If anyone has a solution for these problems, please let me know.

Comment: I found a better solution. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "contextual menu". It's a bit old and a bit outdate, but, take a look this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313)

A "contextual menu" in the position of the mouse its like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nalkfb?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
<div class="container" (click)="openTemplate($event,template)"></div>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="popup">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button (click)="close('hi')">close</button>
 </div>
</ng-template>

export class App {
  overlayRef: any;
  sub!: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private overlay: Overlay,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  openTemplate({ x, y }: MouseEvent, template: any) {
    this.close(null); //<--to be sure it's dispose all
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(this.getOverlayConfig(x, y));
    //I can pass "data" as implicit and "close" to close the menu
    this.overlayRef.attach(
      new TemplatePortal(template, this.viewContainerRef, {
        $implicit: {}, close:this.close
      })
    );

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.sub = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, "click")
      .pipe(
        filter(event => {
          const clickTarget = event.target as HTMLElement;
          return (
            clickTarget != this.overlayRef.nativeElement &&
            (!!this.overlayRef &&
              !this.overlayRef.overlayElement.contains(clickTarget))
          );
        }),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.close(null);
      });
  
    })
  }

  close=(data: any)=> {
        this.sub && this.sub.unsubscribe();
        if (this.overlayRef) {
            this.overlayRef.dispose();
            this.overlayRef = null;
        }
    }

  private getOverlayConfig(x: number, y: number): OverlayConfig {
    return new OverlayConfig({
      hasBackdrop: true,
      backdropClass: "popover-backdrop",
      positionStrategy: this.overlay.position()
                             .flexibleConnectedTo({ x, y })
                             .withPositions(this.getPositions()),
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.close(),
    });
  }

  //you need give almost one position
  private getPositions(): ConnectionPositionPair[] {
        return [
            {
                originX: "start",
                originY: "top",
                overlayX: "start",
                overlayY: "top"
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found a solution that I think is easier. See the accepted answer.