# How to create a container for all selected items from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm creating a container to store all of the selected items from the dropdown. I want to style the container so that it can appear right above the dropdown list.

Here's my code: [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="listOfItems" (selectionChange)="someChange($event)"     (openedChange)="comboChange($event)" placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings"     disableOptionCentering panelClass="demo-mat-select-container" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngIf="toppings.value && toppings.value.length" class="items-container">
  <div class = 'parent' *ngFor="let item of toppings.value">
      <button class = 'clear-icon' (click)="deleteItem(item)">x</button>
      <div class = "circle">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**

if one of the selected items has long text simply put it below the previous selected item (**never increase the width size of the selected items container**)

Comment: Solution for the first and main question here is to just filter out the removed item from the array: `this.listOfItems = this.listOfItems.filter(searchedItem => searchedItem !== item);
` instead of using `splice()` which byt the way doesn't change the original array. You needed to assign it to the left side `this.listOfItems = this.listOfItems.splice(...)` however that doesn't work even if you do so.

Comment: As these are two questions i would suggest you promote the second one into a new separate one as that would help others in search.

Comment: @maljukan thanks for your input on the filtering issue! I updated my question so that it focuses on the container for selected items. If you have any thoughts on the styling I'll appreciate it.

Comment: You sure you don't just want the mat-chip-list? https://stackblitz.com/angular/qlendyrypjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there's another aproach that is make our own "menu" using cdk. First take a look to the [SO I wrote in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313)

To open a menu we are going to take account two elements, the "origin" (the div that is clicked) and the "anchor", the element which the overlay are going to attach

The code is like

```
  constructor(
    private overlay: Overlay,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}
  openMenu(origin: any, anchor: any, menu: any) {
    this.close(null);
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(this.getOverlayConfig(anchor,origin));
    this.overlayRef.attach(
      new TemplatePortal(menu, this.viewContainerRef, {
        $implicit: this
      })
    );
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sub = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, "click")
        .pipe(
          filter(event => {
            const clickTarget = event.target as HTMLElement;
            return (
              clickTarget != origin &&
              (!!this.overlayRef &&
                !this.overlayRef.overlayElement.contains(clickTarget))
            );
          }),
          take(1)
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.close(null);
        });
    });
  }
  close = (data: any) => {
    this.sub && this.sub.unsubscribe();
    if (this.overlayRef) {
      this.overlayRef.dispose();
      this.overlayRef = null;
    }
  };


  change(value: any, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (!isChecked)
      this.value = (this.value || []).filter(
        (x: any) => x != value
      );

    if (isChecked)
      this.value = this.toppingList.filter(
        (x: any) =>
          x == value || (this.value && this.value.indexOf(x) >= 0)
      );
    //when some change, we reposition the overLayRef
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.overlayRef && this.overlayRef.updatePosition();
    });
  }
  private getOverlayPosition(origin: any): PositionStrategy {
    const positionStrategy = this.overlay
      .position()
      .flexibleConnectedTo(origin)
      .withPositions(this.getPositions())
      .withPush(false);

    return positionStrategy;
  }

  private getOverlayConfig(anchor: any,origin:any): OverlayConfig {
    return new OverlayConfig({
      hasBackdrop: false,
      backdropClass: "popover-backdrop",
      positionStrategy: this.getOverlayPosition(anchor),
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.close(),
      width:origin.getBoundingClientRect().width,
      panelClass:"mat-elevation-z8"
      //you can add anothers properties, see
      //https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#OverlayConfig
    });
  }
  private getPositions(): ConnectionPositionPair[] {
    return [
      {
        originX: "center",
        originY: "bottom",
        overlayX: "center",
        overlayY: "top"
      },
      {
        originX: "center",
        originY: "top",
        overlayX: "center",
        overlayY: "bottom"
      }
    ];
  }
```

And the .html

```
<div class="container-all">
    <div #field class="container-input" (click)="openMenu(field,anchor,tpl)">
        <div>
            <span>{{value || []}}</span>
        </div>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div #anchor [ngClass]="{'chip-list':value && value.length}">
        <mat-chip-list aria-label="Fruit selection">
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of value" removable="true" (removed)="change(fruit,false)">
                {{fruit}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #tpl>
    <div class="checkbox-list">
        <div *ngFor="let topping of toppingList">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="value && value.indexOf(topping)>=0" (change)="change(topping,$event.checked)">
                {{topping}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

The stackblitz, as usual [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw-hkbneh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

Another stackblitz with a look "more material" [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw-utnhbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet is using a mat-menu, not a mat-select. Some like

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <input matInput readonly [value]="listOfItems || []"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"/>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="chipList">
        </ng-container>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu-select">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="chipList">
        </ng-container>
        <div *ngFor="let topping of toppingList">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="listOfItems && listOfItems.indexOf(topping)>=0"
                (change)="change(topping,$event.checked)">
                {{topping}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
<ng-template #chipList>
    <mat-chip-list aria-label="Fruit selection">
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of listOfItems" removable="true" (removed)="change(fruit,false)">
            {{fruit}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</ng-template>
```

See that the menu are enclosed by a `<div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">` to can check the checkboxes

The code to the checkboxes is a typical to change a variable to result an array

```
change(value:any,isChecked:boolean){
    if (!isChecked)
       this.listOfItems=(this.listOfItems || []).filter((x:any)=>x!=value)

    if (isChecked)
      this.listOfItems=this.toppingList.filter((x:any)=>x==value ||(this.listOfItems && this.listOfItems.indexOf(x)>=0))

  }
```

here is an [ugly stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw-tzt1dj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

**Update** to control the menu we can assing a template variable to MenuTrigger, see that we add `#menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger` to the input so we can use the methods and properties of the [matMenuTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger)

```
<input #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" matInput readonly 
      [value]="listOfItems || []"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"/>
```

So, we can control better the menu, e.g. we want to open on click in the icon and change the icon if isOpen or not

```
<mat-icon matSuffix (click)="menuTrigger.openMenu()">
    {{menuTrigger.menuOpen?'keyboard_arrow_up':'keyboard_arrow_down'}}
</mat-icon>
```

Or even use the (focus) to open the menu

```
<input (focus)="menuTrigger.openMenu()" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" ...>
```

If we don't want the label of the form field we can use some like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!listOfItems?.length">
    <mat-label >Favorite food</mat-label>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I noticed that the selected items with the matChipRemove are in the same div as the selected items on the mat-menu. I want to have the selected items in a different div just like I have them in the pictures. I also noticed that the arrow doesn't work at all when clicking on it. Any other thoughts on how to get this to work with a typical dropdown? thank you

Comment: you can add the `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"`to the mat-form-field instead to the mat-input. The problem with material-angular is that has no a "dropdown". It's not very dificult make one like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199540/angular-cdk-attach-overlay-to-a-clicked-element/59272313#59272313. As I see you can not use a mat-select becaouse you can not "override" the list of check-box

Comment: so let's say I try to close the menu by clicking outside and if I previously selected items how do I display only those selected items (mat-chip items) in the menu without having to close the whole menu? basically how do I tell the menu "If you have selected items and if user clicks outside the menu , please don't close menu but hide the checkboxes. Otherwise if user didn't select anything simply hide menu" any ideas how to do that? I'm having issues preventing the menu from closing. Thanks

Comment: I like your idea of using mat-menu but do you have another idea of making it look like my pictures and not bind the mat-chips twice like you are doing?

Comment: @progx, I wrote another aproach that use the link I indicated. I know that it's a few complex, but I can not imagine another way that "re-positione" the "menu" when we are adding toppings