# How to build a colour pallete in dropdown in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I need to build a color-pallet in a dropdown similar to mentioned in below image. and but do not want to hardcode the hex values in the code as I will not be limiting the colors in the pallet in future. I wanted to use ngx-color-picker, so that I can enable the color picker in the later versions.[image]

Comment: I suggest you use Angular CDK overlay for it, then your color logic will not be limited. Ref: https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/examples

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you can simply do that ?

```html
<input type="color">
```

It renders a full color palette for you with little to no code.

Comment: It renders an complete color picker. Initially I want to keep limited colors in the the pallet. Later color picker can be rendered in the later releases with these limited colors in the presets. As shown in the image

Comment: Then your question is too broad, please limit to issues you encounter when trying to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Using the link @vicnoob indicate, you can "easy" write a component like

```
<button
  [class.dropup]="upDropdown"
  (click)="isOpen = !isOpen"
  type="button"
  cdkOverlayOrigin
  #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
>
  <div [style.background-color]="value"></div>
  {{ label }}
</button>

<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayPositions]="positions"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayWidth]="220"
  (positionChange)="positionChange($event)"
>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button
      *ngFor="let color of colores"
      (click)="value = color; isOpen = false"
      [style.background-color]="color"
      [style.border]="color=='#ffffff'?'1px solid silver':null"
    ></button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Where you define some `@Input`

```
  @Input() label = 'Choose color';
  @Input()colores = ['#e91c2b','#f48a1d','#eacf2a','#0aa350',
                     '#44a0e3','#cc0098','#663398','#6e340e',
                     '#101113','#cccccc','#ffffff']
```

For the positions we need define a serie of predefined ConnectedPosition, some like

```
export const POS: {
  top: ConnectedPosition;
  right: ConnectedPosition;
  bottom: ConnectedPosition;
  left: ConnectedPosition;
} = {
  top: {
    originX: 'start',
    originY: 'top',
    overlayX: 'start',
    overlayY: 'bottom',
    offsetY: -5,
    offsetX: 0,
    panelClass: '',
    weight: 120,
  },
  ...
}
```

In this way, we can define another input

```
  @Input('positions') set _positions(value:string[])
  {
    this.positions=value.map(x=>POS[x]|| null).filter(x=>x)
  }
```

The last detail is control the position of the cdkdrop to change the class of the "caret". For this we need use [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

```
  positionChange(event) {
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
      this.upDropdown = event.connectionPair.overlayY == 'bottom' ? true : null;
    });
  }
```

Well, implement [controlValueAccesor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) to make a Custom Form Component

And "voilá". This is the [final stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oelpve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnel-color-picker%2Fnel-color-picker.component.ts)

**Update** a bit improvement:

When a color of colores are white we need add a border if white

```
<button *ngFor="let color of colores"  
    (click)="value=color;isOpen=false" 
    [style.background-color]="color" 
    [style.border]="color=='#ffffff'?'1px solid silver':null">
```

When we use the component if we pass a value that is not in colores array it's good add this color

```
writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value=value;
    if (this.value && !this.colores.find(x=>x==value))
      this.colores.push(value)
}
```

If we choose pass the position "top" we can add the class dropup

```
  @Input('positions') set _positions(value:string[])
  {
    this.positions=value.map(x=>POS[x]|| null).filter(x=>x)
    if (this.positions[0].overlayY=='bottom')
      this.upDropDown=true
  }
```

The "enabled" are not using,

```
<button [disabled]="disabled?true:null" 
        [style.opacity]="disabled?'.5':null"
        ...
</button>
```