# Create a custom dropdown component with checkboxes in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10, angular11

I want to create a dropdown using angular multi checkbox, but I'm not sure how to do it in the "Angular way", that component will use in some places as a form control.

```
<app-custom-dropdown label="Group List" [options]="groupOptions" formControlName="groupsList"></app-custom-dropdown>
```

[image]

```
elected: any = [];
  disabled = false;
  private onTouched!: Function;
  private onChanged!: Function;

  public checkedOptions: any = [];


  

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.selected.push(value);
    console.log(this.selected);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
```

Comment: Here are a couple of good guides I've used in the past: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/ & https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2

Comment: The more difficult part is make the "dropdown". Some time ago, someone ask about creare a "colour palette in dropdown". If you want check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905665/how-to-build-a-colour-pallete-in-dropdown-in-angular/73908751#73908751) related

Comment: NOTE: Your checkedOptions should be an [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)