# Looking for a standalone dropdown component for Angular that does not use Material

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Sending out a general question to see if there are any good alternatives to Material for a dropdown menu, like `mat-menu` from Material. Trying to move away from Material, but have not been able to find any dropdown components that can be positioned as in having it open either downwards, upwards, leftwards and rightwards, or can have multilevel sections. Flowbite has a nice dropdown but do not want to import the whole JS file for one thing.

Currently built my own dropdown component but it still uses `mat-menu` to handle the trigger effect for onhover and click.

Pages is a @Input item[].

Comment: if you want to make yourself I hope you can inspirate in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905665/how-to-build-a-colour-pallete-in-dropdown-in-angular/73908751#73908751) about create a dropdown using [cdkConnectedOverlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngb-dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)

Only rememeber use `autoClose="outside"` (and close manually) when you have a nested submenu

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" autoClose="outside">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>
                Toggle dropdown
            </button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
                <div ngbDropdown placement="right-top">
                <button ngbDropdownItem ngbDropdownToggle>Another Action</button>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu>
                <button ngbDropdownItem>Another action of action</button>
                <button ngbDropdownItem>Something more action of action</button>
                </div>
            </div>
                <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dz1hbo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-basic.html)